# Makefile header directory errors

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I am trying to figure our an error I keep getting with make.  I have several source files located in `assign1` directory along with a `includes` directory (contains `bb.h`).  What I am trying to do is include the `bb.h` header file when I am creating `gq.o` file.  All the other object files compile fine except `gq.o` due to this error:

```
z1755294@hopper:~/assign1/assign1$ make
g++ -c fr.cc
g++ -c vw.cc
g++ -c ac.cc
g++ -c pg.cc
g++ -c gq.cc -I./includes
g++ -o output fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o
gq.o: In function `main':
gq.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
fr.o:fr.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
vw.o: In function `main':
vw.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
fr.o:fr.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'output' failed
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

this is my Makefile:

```
output: fr.o vw.o ac.o pg.o gq.o
        g++ -o fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o output

fr.o: fr.cc pg.h
        g++ -c fr.cc

vw.o: vw.cc ac.h
        g++ -c vw.cc

ac.o: ac.cc ac.h pg.h
        g++ -c ac.cc

pg.o: pg.cc pg.h
        g++ -c pg.cc

gq.o: gq.cc ac.h includes/bb.h
        g++ -c gq.cc -I./includes/bb.h

clean:
        -rm *.o

fr.cc, gq.cc and vw.cc all have main functions inside each of them.  
ac.cc and fr.cc both have fl(); function they have in common.
gq.cc and vw.cc both have x2(); function they have in common.
```

**I am not allowed to edit any of the files below.  The goal is to create a makefile so if the bb.h file were to be changed by someone then the makefile will still work.**

Here is the file structure for each file:

ac.cc

```
#include "ac.h"
#include "pg.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void  y7(void)
{
  cout << "y7()" << endl;
}

void  x2(void)
{
  cout << "x2()" << endl;
  f1();
}
```

ac.h

```
void y7(void);

void x2(void);
```

fr.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "pg.h"

int main()
{
  cout << "program fr" << endl;

  f1();

  return 0;

}
```

gq.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "ac.h"
#include "bb.h"

int main()
{
  cout << "program gq" << endl;

  x2();

  cout << "CONST111: " << CONST111 << endl;
  cout << "CONST222: " << CONST222 << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

pg.cc

```
#include "pg.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void  f1(void)
{
  cout << "f1()" << endl;
}

void  g3(void)
{
  cout << "g3()" << endl;
}
```

pg.h

```
void f1(void);

void g3(void);
```

vw.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "ac.h"

int main()
{
  cout << "program vw" << endl;

  x2();

  return 0;

}
```

includes/bb.h

```
define CONST111   42
#define CONST222   84
```

Comment: This is wrong: `-I./includes/bb.h`, it should point only to the *directory*, not the file: `-I./includes`. Of course `bb.h` must exist in that directory.

Comment: ok I fixed that problem with your suggestion, now I am getting :             g++ -o fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o output
g++: error: output: No such file or directory
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'output' failed
make: *** [output] Error 1

Comment: **Change:** `g++ -o fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o output` **to:** `g++ -o output fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least two errors in this `Makefile` but its impossible to tell without knowing the file layout:

Here are my fixes:

```
output: fr.o vw.o ac.o pg.o gq.o
        g++ -o output fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o

fr.o: fr.cc pg.h
            g++ -c fr.cc

vw.o: vw.cc ac.h
            g++ -c vw.cc

ac.o: ac.cc ac.h pg.h
            g++ -c ac.cc

pg.o: pg.cc pg.h
            g++ -c pg.cc

gq.o: gq.cc ac.h includes/bb.h # need to give path to bb.h
            g++ -c gq.cc -I./includes

clean:
            -rm *.o
```

If you still have problems post your file layout into the question.You can use this:

```
find .
```

in your project folder.

Comment: I added the find . information above, if you can help me figure this out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3325133 You should add your file structure to the original question. I have revised my answer so that it builds with the file structure you posted. I missed putting the full (relative) path to `bb.h`.

Comment: I have added the file structure for each file, can you help me to get the makefile to compile?

Comment: @user3325133 What is the Makefile supposed to do? There are 3 programs in that list of files and your Makefile is only trying to build one.

Comment: The goal is to create a makefile such that if a change is made to any of the source code files, the project can be rebuilt by typing make at the command line.

Comment: If the project has multiple executables, I should have a default rule to build all of them.  Also there should be a rule to clear out the project to a pristine state.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
gq.o: gq.cc ac.h bb.h
        g++  -c gq.cc -I./includes/bb.h
```

to

```
gq.o: gq.cc ac.h
         g++ -c gq.cc -I./includes
```

or

```
gq.o: gq.cc ac.h includes/bb.h
         g++ -c gq.cc -I./includes
```

The reason your build was failing is due to bb.h not being in the same directory.  You list `bb.h` as a requirement and since it is not there, make attempts to generate it but finds no suitable rule.  You need to either not list `bb.h` as a requirement or specify the file with its path so make sees that it exists.  You also need to just use `-I./includes` to specify the search directory that g++ will look for `bb.h` in.

You will also need to change this:

```
output: fr.o vw.o ac.o pg.o gq.o
    g++ -o fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o output
```

which has many problems.  First and foremost you are trying to link objects with conflicting symbols and your use of the `-o` flag is wrong.  Based on comments and your edits, what I think you want is:

```
output: fr.o vw.o ac.o pg.o gq.o
        g++ -o fr fr.o pg.o
        g++ -o gq gq.o ac.o pq.o
        g++ -o vw vw.o ac.o pg.o
```

This will produce three binaries, `fr`, `gq`, and `vw`, named after the three files with `main()` symbols.  Each only lists the objects necessary for resolving external symbols.

Comment: I did change that and now another error:                                                          g++ -c fr.cc
g++ -c vw.cc
g++ -c ac.cc
g++ -c pg.cc
g++ -I./includes -c gq.cc
g++ fr.o gq.o vw.o ac.o pg.o -o output
gq.o: In function `main':
gq.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
fr.o:fr.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
vw.o: In function `main':
vw.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
fr.o:fr.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'output' failed
make: *** [output] Error 1

Comment: I posted the question with updates, can you help me figure this out?

Comment: Thank you so much, it compiles perfectly.  Just a quick question, if any of the source files changes, will the make work again?  Also when it compiles how come when I type make clean the files fr, gq, and vw still say.  Shouldn't this be cleared and if not, how do remove those files?

Comment: Since those files in the output section you suggested are executables, how do I create a rule to build all of them?

Comment: @user3325133 if any of the files change, make should rebuild them as necessary.  To get `make clean` to work, you need to also remove `fr`, `gq` and `vw` (add them to the `rm`).  You already have a rule to build all of the executables, called `output`.  If that is the first rule in the file, running `make` with no arguments will automatically call `make output` and make your executables.

Comment: Thanks, when I type make, I don't get any file called output, whats going on? I see all the other files it creates like vw, fr, gq, and all .o files, but don't see the output executable file.

Comment: @user3325133 because the rule isn't creating a file called output, that is the name of your target.  If you need to create a file named output you'll have to change the rule to build it.

Comment: So let me try making sense of this, the files fr. gq, and vw are executables?  What would I have to do in order to make a default rule to to build all of these executables with the name output?

Comment: @user3325133 you can't have three executables with the same name.  You can call one of them output, but not all three of them...

Comment: so with the changes you suggested above makes gq, vw and fr files (are these executables already or just source code files?)  The instruction for this assignment says: If the project has multiple executables, you should have a default rule to build all of th executables (does this apply here), I am kinda lost.  Sorry

Comment: @user3325133 yes, those are executables and they are all built by the default rule.  At this point your makefile issue is solved but I can't address the lack of knowledge in how compilers and makefiles work.  I suggest you google some tutorials and try to understand how they all fit together and work.

Comment: Thanks, wil do. So if they are executables why doesn't it make a file called output?  You were really helpfully in making me understand this.

Comment: @user3325133 the `-o` flag means the next thing is the name of the executable.  none of them say `-o output`, so none of them produce a file called output.  This is normal.  Most projects have an `all` target that produces the main executable / library but they do not create a file called `all`.  I am glad I could help.  best of luck to you.

Comment: Oh I get it now, the name output or all is just a command to say to produce executables but doesn't acutally create a name called all or output (in our case).  Now I understand